# What is the type of 'special' operators/instructions in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, we have things like `if`, `elif`, `else`, `break`, `continue`, `pass`, etc. For want of a better word, I'll call them special instructions.

What type are they? If I do something like `type(pass)` I get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: "Keywords"/"Reserved Words"?

Comment: You mean **keywords**?

Comment: They do not have a type. These are keywords, keywords are not objects. These are keywords that the interpreter/compiler understands.

Comment: They're keywords? https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html

Comment: One of you commenters should probably write this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to documentation, the terminology you're looking for is ["Keywords"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

> ### 2.3.1. Keywords
>
> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of
> the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers. They must be
> spelled exactly as written here:
>
> ```
> False      class      finally    is         return
> None       continue   for        lambda     try
> True       def        from       nonlocal   while
> and        del        global     not        with
> as         elif       if         or         yield
> assert     else       import     pass
> break      except     in         raise
> ```

These are language constructs. They are part of the language's [grammar and syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), and *not* objects. The interpreter treats these differently. As such, they are not associated with a `type`, as objects typically are.

If, for any reason, you want to know whether a word is a python keyword (aka, reserved word), you can import the `keyword` module and test -

```
import keyword

keyword.iskeyword('if')
True
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me by a couple of seconds. +1

Answer (score 4):

They're called [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). You can test if a string represents a keyword by using `keyword.iskeyword`:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword("if")
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword("ifo")
False
```